# Where to find pricing formulas for affine stochastic volatility jump-diffusion models?

Tags: stochastic-volatility, pricing-formulae, jump

Does anyone know a reference where I can find the pricing formulas for vanilla calls in the affine stochastic volatility jump diffusion class of models such as SVJ and SVJJ?

I am looking for something analogous to the following formulas which apply to the Heston (square root) affine stochastic volatility model:

\begin{align}
 c(t)
  & = \frac{e^{-\alpha\log K}}{\pi}\int_0^\infty dv e^{-i v \log K}\rho(v) \\
 \rho(v)
  & = \frac{e^{-r(T-t)}\phi(v-i(\alpha+1);T)}{\alpha^2+\alpha-v^2 + i(2\alpha+1)v} \\
 \phi(u;T)
  & = \mathbb{E}^{Q_B}_t[e^{i u \log S(T)}], \\
 \phi(u;T)
  & = e^{i u[\log S(t)+(r-\delta)(T-t)]-\frac{1}{\sigma_v^2}\left[\bar{v}\kappa\left(a(T-t) + 2\log\beta\right)+v_0 \gamma \right]} \\
 \beta
  & = \frac{1-ge^{-d (T-t)}}{1-g} \\ 
 \gamma
  & = \frac{a(1-e^{-d (T-t)})}{1-g e^{-d (T-t)}} \\
 d
  & = \sqrt{(i\rho \sigma_v u - \kappa)^2 + \sigma_v^2(iu + u^2)} \\
 g
  & = a/b \\
 a
  & = i\rho\sigma_v u-\kappa + d \\
 b
  & = i\rho \sigma_v u-\kappa - d
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Do these work for you?

P34 of http://web.mit.edu/junpan/www/SVJ.pdf

P1360 of http://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/DuffiePanSingleton2000.pdf

P2045 of http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/bakshi.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One of these two books may help you:

- [A Guide to Quantitative Finance](http://riskbooks.com/a-guide-to-quantitative-finance)
- [Option Pricing via Quadrature](http://riskbooks.com/option-pricing-via-quadrature)

They are both from the same author. Both price European vanilla options under various stochastic processes.